# Injecting mocks in a Robolectric test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have to build a Robolectric test for a particular `Activity` that has a private field (a presenter). In order to inject a mock into that field I used reflection, since the project I'm working on has no Dependency Injection framework.

My test setup is as follows:

**MyActivityTest.java**

```
public class ConsumoViewTest {

@Mock
MvpConsumo.Presenter mockPresenter;

private MyActivity view;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    ActivityController<MyActivity> activityController =
        Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class);
    view = activityController.get();
    try {
        FieldUtils.writeField(view, "presenter", mockPresenter, true);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e){
        //Exception handling
    }
    activityController.setup();
}
```

As part of my `Activity` setup, it creates and adds a `Fragment` and during `OnAttach()` the `Fragment` calls the getter for the presenter. Now, the thing I can't understand is that the `Activity` returns a real presenter instead of the mock I injected. This real presenter eventually calls my real model and my real webservice which is obviously not ideal for testing.

Does anyone now why my mock is being ignored on this scenario?

Comment: Great that you found the answer. Why do you use reflection to inject presenter?

Comment: Due to project constraints I can't include Dagger2 or other DI frameworks. Using reflections for testing a private field is bad, but I don't think that creating a `setPresenter` method just for testing would be any better

Comment: No needs for DI frameworks. This approach is problematic when you don't control over lifecycle you not always can stop the process to inject dependency before `when` during the test

Comment: I'm using Roboelectric for the test, so I have control over the lifecycle of the Activity during the test. Having said that, I'm curious about what do you think is a better approach to inject the presenter here

Comment: I meant, you still can not split `onCreate()` or any other method of the class that is under the test. So if you need to control exactly place where things are in injected then your approach will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing the question I realized what the problem was. My reflection does work and the presenter is being initialized as a Mock, but I forgot that during `Activity.OnCreate()` the presenter is initialized as a real presenter, thus overriding the Mock I had injected previously.

Comment: I got the same problem , my presenter initializes when activity is created, and presenter looks for data in database thus my test does not work , how can i mock my presenter any idea??